# Getting null when filter django model by datetime

Tags: python, sql, django, datetime

I have imported datetime as `import datetime`

I need to count database values filtered by datetime in my django model as:

```
def post_left_count(self):

        return self.post_set.filter(expiry_date=datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 27)).count()
```

It returns `0` but it should have returned a value 50 which is my database entries.

If i run this command into my sql shell:

```
select title , expiry_date from tblpost where expiry_date = '2013-10-27 00:00:00';
```

it results into 50 rows.

I don't know why above function is returning 0 instead of 50?

Comment: which means both dates are not equal! print the sql query with `self.post_set.filter(expiry_date=datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 27)).count().query` method and compare.

Comment: what does `self.post_set.filter(expiry_date=datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 27)).__query__.str__()` prints?

Comment: Also, what is `post_set`?

Comment: @alecxe post_set returns all the posts from post model

Comment: my query() shows expiry_date is being equal to 2013-10-26 18:30:00 instead of given (2013, 10, 27).... Why so? Why its changing to previous day?

Comment: Try using `datetime` from djago's timezone util as `django.utils.timezone.datetime(2013, 10, 27)`. You are most likely getting into timezone settings issue.

Comment: @uday.blob this is because you have timezone support turned on..

Comment: @alecxe So how should i be resolving it?